# Can hair follicle miniaturisation affect hair color?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, hair

We all know that follicle miniaturisation affects hair texture, making it look thinner(the hair shaft/root itself will be thinner), but does it affect hair color as well? So if an individual has thick mid brown hair in his/her 20s, hair follicle miniaturisation kicks in in the 40s. Does this person's hair look light brownish due to hair follicles being thinner, fewer, and they reflect light better? Is my hypothesis right? A thinner hair shaft/follicle reflects light better, ie becomes more transparent? Is this broscience on my part, or am I right? I have a hard time believing that a person's hair color doesn't look lighter/more frail if you will, after miniaturisation kicks in.